# Me aparecen valores repetidos al hacer una consulta

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo esta tabla categorias:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
`idcategoria` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombrecategoria` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idcategoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Y esta de gastos:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gastos` (
`idgasto` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cantidadgasto` int(50) NOT NULL,
`fecha` date NOT NULL,
`idcategoria` int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idgasto`),
 CONSTRAINT fk_categoria
    FOREIGN KEY (idcategoria) 
        REFERENCES categoria(idcategoria)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Datos:

```
    insert into categoria (idcategoria,nombrecategoria) values (5, "gasolina");
    insert into categoria (idcategoria,nombrecategoria) values (15, "comida");
    insert into categoria (idcategoria,nombrecategoria) values (25, "ropa");
    insert into categoria (idcategoria,nombrecategoria) values (35, "gimnasio");
    insert into gastos (idgasto,cantidadgasto,fecha,idcategoria) values (100, 25,"2022-03-22",5);
    insert into gastos (idgasto,cantidadgasto,fecha,idcategoria) values (105, 30,"2022-03-23",15);
    insert into gastos (idgasto,cantidadgasto,fecha,idcategoria) values (110, 40,"2022-03-25",25);
```

Mediante esta select:

```
SELECT distinct g.cantidadgasto, c.nombrecategoria, g.fecha 
from gastos g, categoria c 
inner join gastos on gastos.idcategoria = c.idcategoria;
```

Y no consigo que me lo muestre sin repetir, no se si esta mal la tabla gastos o lo que esta mal es la select el caso es que quiero que me lo muestre asi:

Cantidad Gasto || Nombre Categoria || Fecha

Comment: Probaste agrupar después del inner join? no veo en el script ningún group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prueba con esto:**

- No uses el `distinct`
- No hagas `from` de 2 tablas, no es necesario si ya le aplicas el `inner join`

```
select g.cantidadgasto, c.nombrecategoria, g.fecha 
from gastos g
inner join categoria c on c.idcategoria = g.idcategoria
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas utilizar el distinct

y la consulta bueno yo las hago así:

```html
Select gastos.idgasto,gastos.cantidadgasto, gastos.fecha,gastos.idcategoria
From gastos 
INNER JOIN categoria ON categoria.idcategoria=gastos.idcategoria
group by gastos.idgasto // en caso que lo requieras
```